# jQuery Horizontal Accordion Space To Far Right Whilst Animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've created a horizontal accordion in jQuery, starting here as a base:

http://www.webdesign.org/html-and-css/tutorials/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion.15528.html

When it animates, a small amount of space is added to the far right which causes the tabs on the right hand side to move a bit. It doesn't look very good. It's all the more noticeable on my accordion with the white background and the single pixel border around it all.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? Perhaps some kind of hack to keep the items to the right in a fixed position?

My accordion is as below where each | is a tab image and its content is displayed to the right of it (the far left tab is open below):

| content | | |

Many thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your page and code? From my guess it sounds like you should try

position: fixed;
max-width: 600px; /*example width */

This normally does the trick.

Comment: No such luck I'm afraid, thankyou for your suggestion though. I'm concluding it's just a jQuery IE bug. Site is finished and out the door now anyway! :)